# Proof set theory involving instantiation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

Is it okay to instantiate with the same element in universal and existential instantiation? Here follows my proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem**

> If $A  \subseteq B \setminus C $ and $A \not = \emptyset$, then $B \not \subseteq C$.

**Proof attempt**:

Given: $\forall x , x\in A \rightarrow x \in B \wedge x \not \in C$ ----(1)

and  $\exists x \text{ }  x \in A $ --------(2)

Goal: $\exists x, x \in A \wedge x \not \in C$

The objective is to find $x$?

Universal quantification of (1) $x_0 \in A  \rightarrow x_0 \in B \wedge x_0 \not \in C $

Existential  quantification of (2)
$x_0 \in A$

By modus ponens,

$ x_0 \in B \wedge x_0 \not \in C $

By existential introduction,

$ \exists x,  x\in B \wedge x \not \in C $

Hence proved.

Comment: Should the assumption be $A\neq\varnothing$ instead of $A=\varnothing$?

Comment: yea. my bad. I edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general idea works, but the execution is problematic. You're not allowed to unpack the $\exists x.\cdots$ to instantiate $x$ to something that *already* has a meaning. (Exactly what makes this illegal will depend on the precise formulation of the inference rules for quantifiers in the proof system you're working with, which you have not revealed -- so I can only claim that *if* you look them over properly you will find that they don't allow what you're doing).

What you *can* do, however is *start* by opening up the $\exists$, getting $c\in A$ for some fresh $c$. Once you've done that, *then* you can instantiate the universally quantified variable to $c$, because you *are* allowed to instantiate a $\forall$-quantified to something you already know what is.

Again, the precise details of how to justify that formally depend on the details of how your proof system works.

Comment: The problem is order of instantiation? Got  it